# asyncValidate on fieldArray

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, redux-form-validators

How to get async validation to trigger on a specific Field component inside of a FieldArray. I have something like:

Scenario is same as here: [redux-form - asyncBlurFields with FieldArray Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185022/redux-form-asyncblurfields-with-fieldarray-component)

Let's say I have 5 input fields and on 4th I make some mistake and asyncValidate throws error. How do you return error on that field?

Comment: Are you asking for the structure of error for specific field component of array?

Comment: Solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/y3rr8rnlxv

Comment: I think this is best put in a SO response (below) instead of a separate link